# ¿Uso correcto de la función .tag con ImageView?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Tengo una parte del proyecto en la que intento mostrar una imagen a partir de un tag asociado a un ImageView. Por ejemplo, al ImageView X cargo una imagen morada pero a su vez le hago un .tag en el que le asigno otra imagen distinta. Más adelante lo que hago es que al pulsar la imagen, carga la imagen que tenía asociada mediante el .tag que hice antes. El problema está en que si pulso la imagen me da el siguiente error: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference". ¿Habría otra manera de hacerlo más correcto. Gracias. Os lo muestro en código

```
    // Mostar una imagen completamente morada
    miImageView1.setImageResource(R.Drawable.morado)
    // Asociar mediante tag otra imagen distinta para cargarla al pulsar sobre la imagen
    miImageView1.tag = R.drawable.imagen1
    
    ...

    // Al pulsar sobre la imagen se muestra la que tenía asociada en el tag
        miImageView1.setOnClickListener {
            // En la linea de abajo se produce el error
            val s: String = miImageView1.tag.toString()
            val a: Int = s.toInt()
            miImageView1.setImageResource(a)
```

Comment: No entiendo, ¿Por qué usas `tag` ?Si lo que quieres es cambiar la imagen, lo único que debes hacer es que al presionar el `ImageView` le asignes la imagen: `miImageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen1)`

Comment: La temática de la aplicación es un juego de memoria de estos que tienes que emparejar dos imágenes ocultas. Lo que necesito es que la imagen aparezca oculta pero que al pulsarla coja la que tiene asignada en el tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues, la solución sería evitar tantos casteos y hacerlo directo:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val iv = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv)
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.morado)

    iv.setOnClickListener{
        iv.tag = R.drawable.verde
        Log.d("TAG", "onCreate: ${iv.tag.toString().toInt()}")
        iv.setImageResource(iv.tag.toString().toInt())
    }
}
```

Comment: Genial ahora sí funciona. E sla forma correcta de obtener los datos de un .tag. Gracias.

Comment: Que bueno que te haya servido :D